# Custom url plugin for Jira

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Is it possible to make a plugin for Jira that behaves as custom url?

For example, suppose if I have jira on http://jira.example.com and I want to get some data from e.g. http://jira.example.com/record/{id}, where id is parameter for plugin. And output data is audio stream.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [JIRA plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Plugin+Guide) with a [REST module](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/REST+Plugin+Module) to display arbitrary content with a URL similar to the following:

http://jira.example.com/rest/record/{id}.

If you prefer, you could write it as a straight [servlet module](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Servlet+Plugin+Module) instead, with a URL such as this:

http://jira.example.com/plugins/servlet/record/{id}

If you want to expose an endpoint at the main http://jira.example.com/record level, I am not aware of any way to do that within a plugin. (It should be possible, albeit not very portable, by editing the configuration files in the JIRA program directory.)